# Weird php crash while rendering a blade template in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, crash

As in title, php keeps crashing on me with following exception:

```
***********************
*  EXCEPTION DETAILS  *
***********************

DetailID = 1
    Count:    1
    Exception #:  0XC00000FD
    Stack:        

        WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
        php5!php_pcre_exec
```

while using extended blade compiler to precompile components for a basic cms. This page works fine until some unknown character limit is met, after which it crashes every time. I am using ob_start, eval, ob_end_clean if eval throws an exception and ob_get_contents to return parsed component to variable. Output buffering is On (no limit, for debugging of this problem). Memory limit is 128MB and it never goes over 3MB on this page, when it works, checked with memory_get_usage(true).

Thanks

Edit:
I've just hit another version of same problem on same page: it looks like a part of the component page was generated, but then suddenly, when reaching one of Form::select it's cropped and Whoops page is pushed into buffer, but there's only part of it, it's cropped too and that's send back to browser. It looks like eval crashes end it throws an exception, that's not being handled properly. Moreover, output buffer is not flushed despite this:

```
try {
   eval('?>'.$compiledTemplate);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   ob_end_clean();
   throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing pcre.recursion_limit and pcre.backtrack_limit on your php.ini?

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Maury, I've set them both to 10M and it's still happening. Basically, .blade.php file compiles without any problem with and if I paste this `                    <div class="btn btn-xs btn-primary minimise pull-right">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
                    </div>` button six times, php crashes.

Comment: You may have to increase the general memory limit. memory_get_usage(true) gives you the amount of memory allocated to your php script, not the amount of memory being used by a script